# Powershell script is slow to find computers

Tags: powershell

I have a script that is supposed to search for computers in different OUs with the same name in AD.
eg.

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * -Searchbase "OU=domain,DC=home,DC=com"  -properties * |
    Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*XXX09*"} |
        Select name, DistinguishedName
```

Everything works fine, but it is terribly slow, is there any way to speed it up, or build the script differently ?

Comment: Try to use the filter. 

Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "Computer01*"

Answer (score 4):

Not only can you speed-up this by using a filter, but also, using `-Properties *` is asking for **ALL** properties. That is useless and time consuming in this case because you only want to retrieve the Name and DistinguishedName.

`Get-ADCumputer` by default already returns these properties:
`DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Enabled, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID,  UserPrincipalName`.

Try

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "DistinguishedName -like '*XXX09*'" | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName
```

Comment: Most books on PowerShell that go into even the basics of performance issues recommend this; you should have your query return the fewest possible objects and the minimum needed fields from those object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter during the search instead of after will reduce the query time quite a bit.

```
Get-ADComputer -filter 'DistinguishedName -like "*XXX09*"' -Searchbase "OU=domain,DC=home,DC=com" -properties * | select name, DistinguishedName
```

You might need to tune the query slighty, but i tested it with 'name' instead of 'DistinguishedName' and that works just fine (and quite a bit quicker ;))

Comment: It does not work, it does not display any results. I tried the same thing ;)

Comment: I dont think you can filter on DistinguishedName... So either you use Name, or  youll have to live with the longer queue times. sorry.